# Performing Calculation on Filtered DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a Datagridview which I populate from a Dataset created from an XML file. This part works and I can get the entire contents of the Dataset to display in a datagrid. I have the added functionality to filter the datagridview based upon a date and sold flag. This also works OK as the datagridview updates as you cycle through the dates. However I need to do some calculations on the "filtered" datagridview. These calculations are need to convert various currencies into GBP. So after some research on the best way to do this I decided to loop through the visible datagridview and test each of the visible. This is the code I cam up with. Unfortunately when run it all the tests fail and it try to carry out the else clause which then fails with a "Input string was not in a correct format" Exception. However I do not think that is the issue as I put a watch on the Price and Currency values and they "Do not Exist in the current Context"...now im stuck and would appreciate some help. Perhaps im going about this wrong way...

Thanks

Harry

```
for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1["currency", i].ToString() == "USD")
                {
                    myCommission += double.Parse(dataGridView1["commission", i].ToString()) * (double.Parse(dataGridView1["price", i].ToString()) * UStoGB);
                }
                else if (dataGridView1["currency", i].ToString() == "EURO")
                {
                    myCommission += double.Parse(dataGridView1["commission", i].ToString()) * (double.Parse(dataGridView1["price", i].ToString()) * EUtoGB);
                }
                else
                {
                    myCommission += double.Parse(dataGridView1["commission", i].ToString()) * double.Parse(dataGridView1["price", i].ToString());
                }

            }
```

Comment: I tried to do them on the data source originally but just couldn't work out how to manipulate only the filtered data and not all the data in the datasource. Still working my way into programming at the minute so still a lot to learn...thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Use the DataTable.DefaulView, which suppose to be your filtered result and do your calculations, like DataTable.DefaultView.ToTable().Compute(SUM(IIF(currency = 'USD', commission * price * whatewer, IIF(currency = 'EURO', commission * price * whatewer2)))) and so on. You van also use LINQ to do your calculations.

Answer (score 0):

A little alterations with some notes:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    switch (row["currency"].ToString())
    {
        case "USD":
            myCommission += double.Parse(row["commission"].ToString()) * (double.Parse(row["price"].ToString()) * UStoGB); 
            break;

        case "EURO":
            myCommission += double.Parse(row["commission"].ToString()) * (double.Parse(row["price"].ToString()) * EUtoGB); 
            break; 

        case else:
            myCommission += double.Parse(row["commission"].ToString()) *(double.Parse(row["price"].ToString());
            break; 
    }
}
```

Not that this is any better of an answer, but changing this to a foreach will allow you to put a watch on row to determine what the exact names of the columns are.  The column names may be case sensative or the XML import may have done something to the name of the column.

Either way being able to put a breakpoint in and look at the value of row cells

Comment: Thanks Mohgerth, I have just got it working just before I logged on to check posts :) but it wont let me post an answer to my question for another 6 hours. I appreciate the time you have taken and will look at incorporating the case statement in my solution. I will post as soon as I'm able ... thanks

Comment: It's suppose to be a DataGridViewRow in foreach, not DataRow.

Comment: Yes it is.  Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working using

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["currency"].FormattedValue.ToString() == "USD")
        {
            string tempval = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["commission"].ToString();
            myCommission += double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["commission"].FormattedValue.ToString()) * (double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["price"].FormattedValue.ToString()) * UStoGB);
        }
        else if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["currency"].FormattedValue.ToString() == "EURO")
        {
            myCommission += double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["commission"].FormattedValue.ToString()) * (double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["price"].FormattedValue.ToString()) * EUtoGB);
        }
        else
        {
            myCommission += double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["commission"].FormattedValue.ToString()) * (double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["price"].FormattedValue.ToString()));
        }

    }
```

seems that without the `FormattedValue` parameter it and specifying `Rows[i]` and `Cells[i]` it just wasn't getting to the values. Also needed to disable the allowusertoaddrows functionality so it wouldn't count the last line. This is not a problem as it is readonly.

Mohgerth thanks for your reply will look replacing the `for`...`else` section with a `case` now its working as